# bruteforce local software's password

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, brute-force, software

There is a lot of online tools to bruteforce online server like hydra and offline with hashes like hashcat. Yet it seems very weird that there is not a single offline bruteforcing app for software. Like if a make a python app that requires a password, how can I bruteforce the input until it is cracked ?

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why not write your own software which uses xdotool and similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frame challenge: The reason these tools don't exist is that it is generally easier to do traditional cracking, i.e. finding the place in the code where it tests and branches and replace that with a NOP or whatever is required.

For local software, there are almost always easier ways to get past a password than brute-forcing it.

Also, standard answer to all brute-force questions: If your software allows brute-force attacks, it is broken.

Comment: A good strategy against this is to use the password to decrypt some information. For example an iPhone absolutely 100% needs the passcode, or it can’t read most things in its storage. You might be able to get around a “wrong passcode, try again message”, but you can’t make the phone work without the passcode.